# How to use Airflow variables to run more than one Job for a DAG dynamically

Tags: python, airflow

I know how to run DAG's tasks dynamically using *Variable* and it works pretty well until you trigger multiple runs for the same DAG.

i.e., Once a new directory with files are created under *data/to/load/* dir at some point, I have a script written somewhere which will trigger `airflow variables -set dir data/to/load/$newDir` followed by `airflow trigger_dag dyn_test`. Now let's say directory "a" and "b" is created(at similar time) under *data/to/load/* which will make `airflow variable + airflow trigger_dag` calls twice with two different inputs on variable set call(one suffixed with 'a' and the other with 'b' ofcourse). And i see two Jobs running for the DAG in airflow GUI but the problem is that they are both considering same directory value, a or b. This could definitely mean that it takes the final 'airflow variable set' call. How do i resolve it?. What is the way to trigger multiple runs each taking different values(in *dir* variable) to loop dynamically.  My Dag looks something like this:

```
# Using Airflow Variables
from airflow.models import Variable
dir = Variable.get("dir")


args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2004, 11, 12),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dyn_test',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='@once'
)


filesInDir = next(os.walk(dir))[2] 

for file in filesInDir:
    task1 = # change 'file' structure
    task2 = # store changed 'file'

    task1 >> task2
```

Answer (score 1):

The scenario described in your question is one where a *first-in first-out* queue is fitting that is assuming you want to keep the current way of explicitly setting the directory to be processed as a separate sequence.

That said, Airflow CLI `trigger_dags` command allows to pass the `--conf` flag for setting the configuration dictionary passed in the `DagRun` and I'll go that way as you have described that where the variable is set, there is the dag triggered.

http://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#trigger_dag

Here is how that will possibly look in code.

```
airflow trigger_dag dyn_test --conf '{"me_seeks.dir": "data/to/load/$newDir"}'
```

You will set the `provide_context` `kwargs` in what airflow operator you use for the tasks.

The instance of the DagRun can retrieved in the context and the `dir` value set in the configuration retrieved

Say that you defined your tasks with Airflow `PythonOperator`; then your code to retrieved `dir` in the `python_callable` will look similar to this:

```
def me_seeks(dag_run=None):
    dir = dag_run.conf['me_seeks.dir']
```

Comment: but that won't work if i had to use 'dir' variable outside of airflow's task scope the way it's done in my program. i.e., if you look at it, you will notice that I'm using it in the for loop that allows me to create dynamic number of tasks

Comment: I do see that you are using the `dir` outside, loops through files in the `dir` and creates tasks for each of them. However the problem you've described as I have understood is that `dir` is updated by the latest set command and a DagRun executed in a short time earlier sees this value. Did I miss the question?

Comment: yeah. you got that right. That solves "explicitly setting the directory to be processed as a separate sequence". but if i had to use -conf way then I'll loose dynamic task creation technique as the 'conf' would be accessible only in Dag's tasks scope not outside. Hope i was clear? if am wrong again, can you pls write the solution program for my given one?

Comment: My problem was both: `DagRun`s with different input and dynamic task creation nature. But your solution solves the former @Oluwafemi Sule

Comment: In order to keep `dir` module local, you need a way to queue up the values it is set to. You can use Redis or some other external storage that has a queue mechanism for that